# aws lambda access ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a python script running on AWS Lambda that tries to connect to a MariaDB I set up on an EC2 Instance.

The script can't execute because the security group of my EC2 instance only allows certain IPs. How can I allow Lambda functions to access?

Answer (score 8):

The recommended way is to place your Lambda inside VPC. This will allow you to choose a subnet and a security group for your Lambda. So all you need to do after that is to modify your EC2 security group to allow connections either from the Lambda subnet (not so good) or from the Lambda security group (much better).

Comment: I just created a security Group for my Lambda function and added a rule with it to my DB security Group but it does not work. So does the security group of my lambda function need any special rules or can I use the default rules?

Comment: What is DB security group? You said you're running MariaDB on an EC2-instance. Are you using RDS instead?

Comment: yes the mariadb is running on ec2 but without RDS. By DB security Group I was reffering to the securtiy group used for the mentioned instance.

Comment: Try updating your Lambda code to give it a cold start.

Comment: @SergeyKovalev How to create a security group specific to the lambda so that I can add them in the instance's SG. What are the rules to be included within the lambda SG?